# Making Table in LATEX having different rows in different columns

Tags: tables

[image]

I wish to have this table by using  latex code.

Comment: The above duplicate is more generic than my previous found.

Comment: Try the `multirow` package and `\cline{i-j}` (line between row i and row j).

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you wanted ???

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[inner=0.75in,outer=0.65in,top=0.75in,bottom=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm} | c| c| c|}
\hline 
\multirow{2}{*}{more text} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{} \\
\cline{2-4} 
 &   text & text& text \\
\hline
text  & text & text& text \\
\hline
 text & text & text& text \\
\hline
 text & text & text& text \\
\hline
 text & text & text& text \\
\hline
 text & text & text& text \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

You didn't specify anything about the alignment of the text inside the cells, so I just went with the easiest solution.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/U4m8Um1.png?1]